# Difference between two codes: I get false for one and true for another

Tags: ruby

I got these two codes from two websites defining the longest word in a string:

Code 1.

```
def longest_word(sentence)
  words = sentence.split(" ")
  longest_word = nil
  word_idx = 0
  while word_idx < words.length
    current_word = words[word_idx]
    if longest_word == nil
      longest_word = current_word
    elsif longest_word.length < current_word.length
      longest_word = current_word
    end
    word_idx += 1
  end
  longest_word
end
```

Code 2.

```
def LongestWord(sen)
  arr = sen.split.map do |w|
    /[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+/.match(w)
  end
  longest = arr.max_by do |w|
    w.to_s.length
  end
  longest
end
```

But one code gives me true, and one gives me false. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: They will return a String not Bool. How do you call them?

Comment: Please read "[ask]". Please modify your question and be more descriptive: Which returns true and which returns false? What did you try to figure out the answer yourself? As is, your question doesn't show a lot of research or effort: “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421)” is a useful page to read.

Comment: Be careful, as they don't define "word" the same way so the results will be different. `longest_word('foo bar foo_bar_baz') # => "foo_bar_baz"`
vs. `LongestWord('foo bar foo_bar_baz') # => #<MatchData "foo">`

Answer (score 1):

The difference is:

- `LongestWord` returns `MatchData` http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/MatchData.html
- `longest_word` returns `String`

so

```
longest_word(sentence).eql?(LongestWord(sentence).to_s) == true
```